# psql cast parse error during cursor.fetchall()

Tags: python, python-2.7, psycopg2, psql

I have a python code which queries psql and returns a batch of results using `cursor.fetchall()`.
It throws an exception and fails the process if a casting fails, due to bad data in the DB.
I get this exception:

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2cffi/_impl/cursor.py", line 377, in fetchall
    return [self._build_row() for _ in xrange(size)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2cffi/_impl/cursor.py", line 891, in _build_row
    self._casts[i], val, length, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2cffi/_impl/typecasts.py", line 71, in typecast
    return caster.cast(value, cursor, length)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2cffi/_impl/typecasts.py", line 39, in cast
    return self.caster(value, length, cursor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2cffi/_impl/typecasts.py", line 311, in parse_date
    raise DataError("bad datetime: '%s'" % bytes_to_ascii(value))
DataError: bad datetime: '32014-03-03'`

Is there a way to tell the caster to ignore this error and parse this as a string instead of failing the entire batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "hack" the parser of `psycopg2cffi` to return DATE objects as strings instead:

If you look in the [code](https://github.com/chtd/psycopg2cffi/blob/6a8dec51dada0d980df270c34d91f771aba4bd01/psycopg2cffi/_impl/typecasts.py#L405) you can see the registration of the DATE parser, so you can replace the serializer of DATE in your code.

```
import psycopg2cffi

psycopg2cffi._impl.typecasts._default_type('DATE', [1082],
                                  psycopg2cffi._impl.typecasts.parse_string)
```

Of course this can be done, for every type.

Answer (score 0):

change your psql query to cast and get the date column as string

e.g. select date_column_name:: to_char from table_name.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! the second solution is what I'm trying to do , but `psycopg2cffi` is a python library that I'm using, and if I catch the exception on my code then the `fetchall()` will not be fully executed an remain Null